# Edit and delete remote mysql record from link in ajax json list

Tags: mysql, ajax, json, cordova

OK new at this / long time away from it...

I have a json list created thus:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.somewebsite.com/land.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                var balance = '<p>' + item.itemm + ' ' + item.amount + ' ' + item.status +
                    ' ' + '<a href="#" onclick="loadRecord(' + i + ');">edit</a>' + ' ' +
                    '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRecord(' + item.id + ');"> delete</a>' +
                    '</p><hr>';
                total2 = total2 + parseInt(item.amount);
                $("#mylbl").append(balance);
                $("#mylbl5").html(total2);
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
```

I'm using this method as I'm using phonegap...I have display items and add items working but want to add in edit and delete functionality...

I'm trying to add edit and delete links on each row (as above) but just cant get it sorted....

Only at delete stage .. and have tried this delete function..

```
function deleteRecord(id) // Get id of record . Function Call when Delete Button Click..

{
mysql_connect("localhost","454547_yeah","password");
mysql_select_db("454487_mydbdb");
 var deleteStatement = mysql_query("DELETE FROM balance WHERE id=?");


    db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(deleteStatement, id, onError); alert("Delete Sucessfully"); });

}
```

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated ....I've trawlled the web and found nought that might help...

Comment: `deleteRecord` needs to make another AJAX request passing the `id` so that you can do that on your server. Phonegap cannot directly connect to a mysql database on a remote server

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
formDataEdit = {
    itemm: $("#itemm"),
    amount: $("#amount"),
    status: $("#status")
};
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.somewebsite.com/delete.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    data: formDataEdit,
    success: function(data, status) {
        alert("Edit successful");
    },
    error: function() {
        output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
});
formDataDelete = {
    id: $("#id")
};
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.somewebsite.com/delete.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    data: formDataDelete,
    success: function(data, status) {
        alert("Delete successful");
    },
    error: function() {
        output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
});
```

html

```
<b><a onclick="edit(1);">Edit</a> | <a onclick="delete(1);">Delete</a></b>
```

js

```
currentPage = {};
currentPage.edit = function(id){ //also can use for delete
    alert(id);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that...that was actually next step I was going to attempt implement but you have detailed it perfectly...Issue I'm having really is grabbing and passing the itemm 'id' when either edit or delete links are clicked? My code doesn't seem to grab it?

Comment: Hi..only HTML that's relevant is
    <body> 
    <h2>View Balance</h2>
    <br/>
    <a href="index.html">Back to Home Page</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <b>BALANCE: <span id="mylbl6"></span></b>
    <br/>
    <b>CREDIT</b>
    <span id="mylbl"></span>
    <b>TOTAL: <span id="mylbl5"></span></b>
    <br/>
    <a href="index.html">Back to Home Page</a>'
   
    </body>

Comment: you can use onclick(param);

Comment: Thanks...I think I may have sorted it...but can you expand a wee bit on that comment :)

Comment: Thanks Dato'...been trying that here but not working...am I right in assuming that the ajax code and js code simply go in the <head>? Also I've been simply trying to grab the id and display in the alert but even that fails...

Comment: Ok I still can't even grab the id on link or button click....I reckon if I can achieve this I should be able to move on....is this an issue grabbing data from Ajax generated HTML? Any assistance much appreciated...

Comment: I've managed to get id of item clicked and pass it to a delete.php file so I have delete working...now for editing item data....what's my best options for edit? I want to populate update form based on id and be able to edit and save (update) .. struggling here; any pointers greatly appreciated :)

Comment: this link can help you how to to edit, http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/07/15/simple-hybrid-mobile-app-using-cordova-and-ratchet-2-complete/